# Want to write Junit for the beow function

Tags: jquery, unit-testing

Validating the input fields from HTMl form .Trying to write unit test case.Need help to implement jasmine unit test case in Jasmine

```
var object = {};
var myclass=function requiredFieldValidator(jQuery) {
    object.utility = {
        requiredFieldValidation : function validation() {
            jQuery("#InsertQuestionAndAnswer").validate({
                rules : {
                    Question : "required",
                    Answer : "required",
                },
                messages : {
                    Question : "Question Cannot be Blank",
                    Answer : "Answer Cannot be Blank",
                },
                submitHandler : function(form) {
                    form.submit();
                }
            });
        }
    } 
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        object.utility.requiredFieldValidation();
    });
}(jQuery);
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you need help with? What's going wrong when you try to do the unit test case in Jasmine? Your question as it's written doesn't make it clear where you are getting stuck.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am new to unit testing so I am not sure how jasmine works.But I was able to test it with JSunit,